# Do there exist non-constant function f, g for which the "naive quotient rule" holds?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

A common mistake students make is applying a naive form of the quotient rule to functions of the form f/g, mistakenly applying the product rule and arriving at f'g+g'f for the derivative.  What I'm curious about are for what functions this *is* true, that is for what functions
f'g+g'f = (f'g-g'f)/(g^2).

Comment: You may want to convert this to a system of ODEs and ask about that giving this as a context, or ask "When is $(fg)' = \Big(\frac fg\Big)'$?". I recommend this because a "native quotient rule" is nothing I would come up with to refer to what you say. I thought you were asking about when is $\Big(\frac fg\Big)' = \frac{f'}{g'}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle f'g + fg' = \frac{f'g - g'f}{g^2}$, then integrating we have $(fg) = (f/g) + C$ or

$$f = C\frac{g}{g^2 - 1}$$

So there are infinitely many examples. Here's one:

$$g(x) = x, \ \ \ \ C = 1, \ \ \ \ \ f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 - 1}$$

Then $$(fg)' = \left( \frac{x^2}{x^2 - 1} \right)' = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x^2 - 1} \right)' = \left( \frac{1}{x^2 - 1} \right)' = \left( \frac{f}{g} \right)'$$

Answer (score 0):

There are functions.

Take $g(x)=x$, hence $g'(x)=1$.

Then you want to solve $x^3f'+x²f=xf'-f$, that is

$\dfrac{f'}{f}=-\dfrac{1+x²}{x^3-x}$

If you take the right domain, you have a solution.

EDIT: the other answer is much more elegant...